# How do I check a MySQL column to make sure it contains a value?

Tags: php, mysql, select, null

I am trying to select all rows from a database where display = 'Y' and announcement != null. How can I check a column to make sure it contains a value?

```
 $qry = "select *   
         from   school
     where  display='Y'
     order by name, announcement, last_update";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$qry = "select *       
         from   school
         where  display='Y'
         and (announcement != '' AND announcement IS NOT null)
         order by name, announcement, last_update";
```

This caters for blank fields as well as null fields.

Comment: the standard SQL way is that any statement that contains NULL should return null, which is why you have use IS NOT NULL or ISNULL()

Comment: Updated. Do your comments still apply?

Answer (score 3):

```
announcement IS NOT NULL
```

or

```
NOT ISNULL(announcement)
```